# scala Play - repeated WS calls - making it Async

Tags: web-services, scala, asynchronous, playframework

From the Play framework's controller I am making a call to external web service, to upload a file there. After the file is uploaded, the external server will process it and I will need to get back the processed file.

Since processing takes potentially a long time, I keep making an http call every few seconds to see if the file exists. Once I get back an OK status, I make another call to retrieve the processed file.

The problem is that I have to repeatedly make the same call, every few seconds, and proceed only after I get an OK status. Currently I got it to  work using *Await* - I keep waiting and making another call until I get the OK status.

Of course, this is blocking and it's a big no-no in Play.

What would be a way to make this asynchronous?

Here is the code that I currently have

```
<code>
 //keep checking until converted file exists, then download                
 futureResponse = fileURLFut.flatMap {
                      convertedFileURL =>                                         
                        //keep checking response status until OK (200)or until too much time passes                                      
                        var counter = 0
                        var respStatus: Int = 0
                        do {                          
                           if (counter == 30) {
                            //waited too long - interrupt the loop
                            throw new RuntimeException("Converted file not found.")
                           }   
                           //TODO this will have to be done without blocking
                           Thread.sleep(2000)
                           counter = counter + 1                      
                           respStatus = Await.result(       WS.url(convertedFileURL).withAuth(user.get, password.get, AuthScheme.BASIC)
                                   .get.map(_.status),  duration.Duration(10000, "millis"))
                           Logger.debug("Checking if file exists...  " + counter + " status = " + respStatus)                                                   
                        } while (respStatus != 200)

                        Logger.debug("File exists. Will download now.")

                        var sss= WS.url(convertedFileURL)
                          .withAuth(user, password, AuthScheme.BASIC)
                          .get
</code>
```

Comment: Is the assumption correct that you have no other interface to query the status of the file? For an example something that only responded to the request after the file has been created?

Comment: Maybe use websockets or something like that? Then you can inform your client when/if the file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def runRequest(...): Future[Result] = 
  WS.url(convertedFileURL).withAuth(user.get, password.get, AuthScheme.BASIC)

def tryOnce(triesLeft: Int): Future[Result] =
  if (triesLeft == 0) Future.failed(throw new RuntimeException("Converted file not found."))
  else runRequest(...) flatMap { res =>
    if (res.status == 200) Future.successful(res)
    else
      akka.pattern.after(2 seconds, using = system.scheduler)(tryOnce(triesLeft - 1))
  }

tryOnce(triesLeft = 30)
```